# Programar em Python

Tags: python, windows

Baixei o python 3.4 no site, mas alguns comandos não funcionam nessa versão em relação ao python2.7 tem alguma diferença? No manual do python2.7, e posso instalar duas?

Comment: Da 2.X pra 3.X houve muitas mudanças sim. Você pode encontrar uma descrição delas [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) (em inglês), ou se tiver dúvida com algum comando específico sugiro [edit] a pergunta com mais detalhes. E é possível instalar duas versões lado a lado sim (até mais de duas), só que você vai ter que escolher no máximo uma pra ser o "Python padrão" (o que vai pro `PATH`, podendo ser chamada sem passar o caminho completo do executável).

Comment: A última versão do python 2.7 foi lançada em 2014, a 3 em 2015

Comment: A 3 já existe há mais tempo, as duas linhas prosseguiram lado a lado por um bom tempo. Que eu saiba, agora a 2.7 só recebe atualizações de segurança e correção de bugs, enquanto a 3 continua evoluindo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você está bem no começo, a maior diferença que vai encontrar em relação à documentação para Python 2 é do comando "print" - ele deixa de ser um comando e passa a ser uma função - 
Então em Python 3, sempre use o print como uma chamada de função, com parenteses:

```
print ("Alô mundo!")
```

Claro que há muitas outras mudanças - muitas só visíveis para usuários mais avançados. Internamente, a maior mudança é que strings em Python 3 contém caractéres de texto, enquanto que em Python 2.x continham sempre "bytes". Os bytes e caractéres de texto coincidem para os números, alguns símbolos, e letras não acentuadas - mas para outros caractéres além desses, você precisa especidicar uma codificação.

Mesmo assim, em nível do aprendizado básico, o Python vai "adivinhar" a codificação de texto do seu sistema operacional e as coisas vão funcionar.

Aqui tem uma aula legal em vídeo falando das maiores diferenças entre as versões:
http://pycursos.com/python-2-vs-3/

E aqui um post com bastante coisa:
https://pythonhelp.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/o-que-mudou-no-python-3/

Uma coisa que é importante entender é que as duas versões continuam snedo mantidas - por que muitos projetos jṕá existentes em Python 2 não foram portados para Python 3. Mas hoje em dia, sem dúvida, é melhor aprender a versão 3.4

Comment: Já programo em C.

Comment: Não vai mudar muito - as maiores diferenças são realmente para quem ja programava em Python2.x. Acho que vale mencionar que o módulo para apps desktop mudou de `Tkinter` (com T maiúsculo) para `tkinter`. Agora, claro que vale a pena voce pegar docuemtnação para Python3 para acompanhar.

Answer (score 2):

1. sim, há várias diferenças entre as versões.
2. Sim, é possível instalar as duas versões de python (2.x e 3.x) na mesma máquina.

Para saber qual versão usar: 
https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3

Para ver as diferenças de forma mais detalhada:
https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html